# Flagging content which may violate TOS

Tags: discussion, flags, copyright, terms-of-service

I've noticed a post on Stack Overflow which asks for help parsing links from a torrent webpage. There's a sample of the type of links presented on the webpage in the post, which are torrents to ripped copy-righted material. I'm unsure if I should flag it for moderation.

Should posts like this be flagged for moderator attention because they violate the [TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal) under "3. Subscriber Content"?

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party,

Comment: @Close voter: why do you think this is a question that is site-specific? This is a TOS question, which is SE wide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That specific case is not a violation of the TOS, since Subscriber Content is defined in the TOS as:

> Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)

So the specific code or text posted should not be an infringement of copyright. Asking to parse a type of link is not prohibited. There is no reason to flag the question as far as I am concerned. If you think the post 'is not useful', it is a valid reason to downvote it (like another post that effectively asks how to send spam). Also, you might not want to answer the question if you feel uncomfortable with it. That is all you can do in my opinion.